# Подключение Qt к "Empty project" в VS15

Tags: c++, qt5

Проект запускается, но есть проблемы:

*-не могу добавить мактрос Q_OBJECT(LNK2001)*

*-при создании формы (ui) по шаблону (“Object reference not set to an instance of an object”)*

**если добавить moc файл с шаблонного проекта на Q_OBJECT не ругается, но связка сигналов и слотов не работает**

Нужно настроить **Custom Build Tool**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Custom Build Tool в рабочей программе**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Для корректной работы с qt из-под msvc необходимо установить аддон (https://download.qt.io/official_releases/vsaddin/). После установки в студии появятся дополнительные пункты меню, облегчающие работу с QT.

Если вы хотите создать свой класс на базе QObject (с сигналами и слотами), то необходимо создать qt проект и добавить qt класс. При использовании аддона, опции в блоке "Custom Build Tools" будут заполнены автоматически.

[image: создание проекта]
[image: создание класса]

Comment: мне нужно подключить qt к Visual C++ -> Empty Project (а не создавать проект по шаблону)